# Php mail function unable to send HTML

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email with a link, the problem im facing is that outlook does not reconize the HTML which is being put in the email.

```
$onderwerp = "test";
$bericht = <<<EOT
<html>
<head>
  <title>Email_test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.link.com/index.php?page=members&id={$last_insert_id}">* the link</a> 
</body>
</html>     
EOT;

$headers = 'From: ' . $verstuurd_van;

mail($naar_1, $onderwerp, $bericht, $headers);
```

Thanks in forehand for the help.

Comment: I highly suggest you to use a library like Swift or PHPMailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to send a HTML email you need to add a few more headers:

```
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

So the entire email becomes something like:

```
$to = 'example@example.com';
        $subject = 'Test';
        $message = "
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>
                    Hallo <b>Example</b>,
                </p>

            </body>
        </html>";
        $headers = "From: example@example.nl\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

just mention the headers in your email script like .

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

so your script will

```
$onderwerp = "test";
$bericht = <<<EOT
<html>
<head>
  <title>Email_test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.link.com/index.php?page=members&id={$last_insert_id}">* the link</a> 
</body>
</html>     
EOT;

$headers = 'From: ' . $verstuurd_van;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
mail($naar_1, $onderwerp, $bericht, $headers);
```

you can take reference from [html email with php](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) or [w3school email html](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)